# JUnit4 - Parameterized test extends parameterized base class - need Cartesian product of them

Tags: junit, junit4, parameterized, parameterized-unit-test

`MyBaseIntegrationTestCase` is a class, which is a parent for ~ 150 test classes.
Now, I want to make `MyBaseIntegrationTestCase` parameterized (parameter is version of external software)

So, I change it to smth like

```java
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public abstract class MyBaseIntegrationTestCase extends MyBaseTestCase{

 @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "with ExternalSoftware-v{0}")
  public static List<String[]> allVersions() {
    return Arrays.asList( ...);
  }

  @Parameterized.Parameter
  public String externalSoftwareVersion;
  
}
```

All children of `MyBaseIntegrationTestCase` became parameterized and run successfully, except the `MyTestClass`, declared as

```kotlin
@RunWith(Parameterized::class)
class MyTestClass(override var myType: ParameterType) : MyBaseIntegrationTestCase() {
  companion object {
    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "with {0}")
    @JvmStatic
    fun allTypes(): Collection<Array<ParameterType>> = ...
}
```

it fails with

> java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor

I want to make all children of MyBaseIntegrationTestCase run parameterized as defined in parent class, and make MyTestClass parameterized on Cartesian product of allType and allVersions

It is impossible to make `MyTestClass` not to extend `MyBaseIntegrationTestCase`, this will require enormous amount of stuff to be copy-pasted.

Could you advice any ideas how to do it in JUnit4?

Answer (score 1):

if anyone interested
classes should be declared as:

```java
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public abstract class MyBaseIntegrationTestCase extends MyBaseTestCase{

 @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "with ExternalSoftware-v{0}")
  public static List<String[]> allVersions() {
    return Arrays.asList( ...);
  }

  @Parameterized.Parameter(0) // important to set index explicitly
  public String externalSoftwareVersion;
  
}
```

and

```kotlin
@RunWith(Parameterized::class)
class MyTestClass : MyBaseIntegrationTestCase() {
  @Parameterized.Parameter(1) // important to set index explicitly
  var myType: ParameterType
  companion object {
    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "with {1} on version {0}")
    @JvmStatic
    fun allTypes(): Collection<Array<Any>> = ... //cartesian product should be here
}
```